# Как оптимизировать использовании "зависимостей" Depends() в классах в FastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

Для внедрения зависимостей в класс, использую Depends()
Пример такого класса:

```
class OrderFactory:

def __init__(self,
             user_access_controls_validate: ValidateCustomRole = Depends(),
             security_scope_validate: ValidateSecurityScope = Depends(),
             validate_security_scope: ValidateSecurityScope = Depends(),
             user_access_controls_factory: UserAccessControlsFactory = Depends(),
             security_factory: SecurityFactory = Depends(),
             current_user=Depends(get_current_user),
             order_service: OrderService = Depends(),
             validator_service: ValidatorService = Depends(),
             custom_validator_service: CustomValidatorService = Depends(),
             organization_partnership_service: OrganizationPartnershipService = Depends(),
             contract_service: ContractService = Depends(),
             order_status_service: OrderStatusService = Depends(),
             order_line_item_factory: OrderLineItemFactory = Depends(),
             email_factory: EmailFactory = Depends(),
             sales_point_service: SalesPointService = Depends(),
             order_line_item_service: OrderLineItemService = Depends()):

    self.user_access_controls_validate = user_access_controls_validate
    self.security_scope_validate = security_scope_validate
    self.validate_security_scope = validate_security_scope
    self.user_access_controls_factory = user_access_controls_factory
    self.security_factory = security_factory
    self.current_user = current_user
    self.order_service = order_service
    self.validator_service = validator_service
    self.custom_validator_service = custom_validator_service
    self.organization_partnership_service = organization_partnership_service
    self.contract_service = contract_service
    self.order_status_service = order_status_service
    self.order_line_item_factory = order_line_item_factory
    self.email_factory = email_factory
    self.sales_point_service = sales_point_service
    self.order_line_item_service = order_line_item_service
```

Только этот класс съедает 100Мб памяти на старте приложения.
Можно ли как-то это оптимизировать?

Comment: Такие записи в конструкторах плохие: `user_access_controls_validate: ValidateCustomRole = Depends()`. Суть в том, что значения параметров высчитываются еще до выполнения конструктора. Не работал с fastapi, поэтому мб получится неподходящее предложение, но эти параметры можно приравнять к `None`, а в конструкторе проверять, что если `None`, то создавать объект `Depends`

Comment: В доках fastapi, Depends в примерах используется для формирования параметров запроса URL, и как замена мидлваре.
Мой пример выше, не мною создан. Такой код мне достался "в наследство".